# how to do substitution of n-1->n in mma

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have defined

```
Subscript[S,n]=Subscript[X,n]+Subscript[S,n-1]
```

For the expression:

```
3*n^2 – 6* n* Subscript[S, -1 + n] ^2
```

I want to do `n-1->n`, but it seems

```
3*n^2 – 6* n* Subscript[S, -1 + n] ^2/. {n-1->n}
```

This way I got

```
3 n^2 - 6 n (Subscript[S, -1 + n] + Subscript[X, n])^2
```

does not do what I want. I want `3*n^2` be re-written as an equivalent using `n-1`, in this case, `3*(n-1)^2+6*(n-1)+3`, then do the substitution to get `3*n^2+6*n+3`

Overall, I want to have:

```
3*n^2+6*n+3+6*n*Subscript[S, n] ^2+6* Subscript[S, n] ^2
```

i.e. I also do not want mma to expand `Subscript[S, n]` in the final result.

How to do this in mma automatically?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why have you defined Xn if you don't want it in your final result? ... I don't get it.

Comment: @belisarius: somehow, after I obtained `3*n^2 – 6* n* Subscript[S, -1 + n] ^2 `, I just do not have X_n any more.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you have the initial definition...

It looks like the result that you want (apart from some signs) follows from the simple

```
In[1]:= (3n^2-6 n Subsuperscript[S, n-1, 2])/.n->n+1//Expand
Out[1]= 3 n^2 + 6 n + 3 - 6 n Subscript[S, n]^2 - 6 Subscript[S, n]^2
```

As for not expanding out the Subscript terms in the final result, maybe you want something like

```
Collect[%1, Subscript[__], Factor]
```

Comment: was I just being really dumb here? n-1->n the way i described is the same as n->n+1?!

Comment: given an expresion involving `Subscript[X, n] + Subscript[S, n - 1]` and the definition `Subscript[S, n] = Subscript[X, n] + Subscript[S, n - 1]`, how do I ask mma to convert it back to Subscript[S, n]?

Comment: @Qiang Li: With regards to the `Collect` I misunderstood what you wanted.  But as I said before, I didn't really get the point (and still don't) of your initial `Subscript[S, n] = Subscript[X, n] + Subscript[S, n - 1]` definition. You'd have to remove the definition or use some form of `Hold` otherwise Mma will always use the rule on `Subscript[S, n]`